# Foundation 5 double-lined top bar (CSS)

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, multiline, navigationbar

What I am trying to make:

[image]

Code:

```
 <div class="contain-to-grid">
      <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name"><h1><a href="#">LOGO</a></h1></li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="right">

        <li><a href="#">RETURN<br/>home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TASTE<br/>new menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ATTEND<br/>events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">EXPLORE<br/>our culture</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BOOK<br/>your place</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</section>
</nav>
      </div>
```

However, what I actually see is this:

[image]

What to do to make what I want? 
Also, how to increase the height of the top bar keeping everything vertically in centre as it is now?

Comment: Post related css also here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove unnecesary **tag closures** and make **proper indentations** in your code because it will help you find mistakes as those closures **much faster**.

```html
<div class="contain-to-grid">
 <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
   <li class="name"><h1><a href="#">LOGO</a></h1></li>
   <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <section class="top-bar-section">
   <ul class="right">
    <li><a href="#">RETURN<br/>home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TASTE<br/>new menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ATTEND<br/>events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EXPLORE<br/>our culture</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BOOK<br/>your place</a></li>
   </ul>
  </section>
 </nav>
</div>
```

2. **Try paste this into your css:**

```css
.top-bar-section > .right > li > a{
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code, however it is not responsive (you have to make it responsive):

```
<div class="contain-to-grid fixed">
  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name"><h1><a href="#">LOGO</a></h1></li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span</a</li>
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="#">RETURN<br/><span style="float: left;margin-top: -20px;">home</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">TASTE<br/><span style="float: left;margin-top: -20px;">new menu</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ATTEND<br/><span style="float: left;margin-top: -20px;">events</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">EXPLORE<br/><span style="float: left;margin-top: -20px;">our culture</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BOOK<br/><span style="float: left;margin-top: -20px;">your place</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>
</div>
```